# Calculation of double integral for the dedicatied region D

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the double integral which represents the intersection of the cylinder and the sphere happened over

$$D:\{(x,y):\, -1\le x\le 1 \,\,\text{ and }\,\, 1-\sqrt{1-x^2} \le y\le 1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\, \}$$

The integral is

$$2\iint_D \sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1}\, d\sigma$$

where $f(x,y) = \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$.
First of all I calculated $f_x^2=\frac{x^2}{-x^2-y^2+4}$, $f_y^2=\frac{y^2}{-x^2-y^2+4}$. However, I am not sure how to take into account the region $D$. Any help to finilize calculation are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the question is to find the surface area of part of a sphere intercepted by the cylinder centred at $(0, 1)$ with radius $1$.  As there is a factor of 2, the surface area includes the top and bottom part of the sphere.

Hence we have

$$2\int_{x = -1}^{1}\int_{y = 1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}^{1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}} \sqrt{f_x^2 + f_y^2 + 1} dydx$$

The integral is too difficult for me.  I would suggest to use spherical coordinates.

$$x = 2cos\theta cos\phi$$
$$y = 2sin\theta cos\phi$$
$$z = 2sin\phi$$

Hence the cylinder in spherical coordinates becomes

$$4cos^2\theta cos^2\phi + 4sin^2\theta cos^2\phi - 4sin\theta cos\phi = 0$$
$$\implies cos\phi = sin\theta$$
$$\implies \theta + \phi = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

The Jacobian for surface area of spherical coordinates is $4cos\phi$.  Then the area is

$$4\int_{\theta = 0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}4cos\phi d\phi d\theta = 8(\pi - 2)$$

Comment: I believe you made a small error at the very end of your calculation. The limits of the integral over $\phi$ should be from $\pi/2-\theta$ to $\pi/2$, so that the final result is $8(\pi-2)$.

Comment: The factor of 4 accounts for 4 times of the area in the first octant.  Hence $\theta$ should be measured from 0 (from the $z = 0$ plane) to the intersection point between the sphere and the cylinder $\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta$.

Comment: My comment was not about the factor 4 but about the range of a variable. And I respect your decision to let the error be uncorrected.

Comment: Please explain why your limit is correct.  I would like to learn.  Thanks.

Comment: If you fix $$ then you will see that  the points of the part of the sphere lying **inside** the cylinder correspond to the values of $$  in the range from $/2−$ to $/2$. To start with, consider $=0$ (the circle lying in $xz$ plane).

Comment: Another way to see the error is to reconsider the unnamed equation after the word "becomes" which has besides the solution $\cos\phi=\sin\theta$ the second one: $\cos\phi=0\implies \phi=\pi/2$ (and not $0$ as you have assumed).

Answer (score 0):

To compute the integral in question:
$$
I=4\iint_D\frac {dxdy}{\sqrt {4-x^2-y^2}}
$$
it is suggestive to use polar coordinates $x=r\cos\phi,y=r\sin\phi$ and observe that the equation for the circle $D:\ \{(x,y):\ x^2+(y-1)^2=1\}$ in polar coordinates reads:
$$
r=2\sin\phi,\quad(0\le\phi\le\pi).
$$

Therefore:
$$\begin{align}
I&=4\iint_D\frac {rdrd\phi}{\sqrt {4-r^2}}\\
&=4\int_0^{\pi}d\phi\int_0^{2\sin\phi}\frac {rdr}{\sqrt {4-r^2}}\\
&=8\int_0^{\pi}(1-|\cos\phi|)d\phi\\
&=8(\pi-2).
\end{align}
$$